# How to fix facebook share dialog security check error?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-share, facebook-debugger

I am trying to share ma image from my website https://fungen.000webhostapp.com/.
at When I click on "Post to Facebook" button of share dialog it was displaying alert box with a message website link is unsecure and also asking to enter capcha code as shown below:
[image]

I found one answer on internet that suggested to debug my website url and fix bugs using facebook object debugger(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/). It was showing the warnings related to inreferred and Missing properties as showin the image below: [image]

So, Since my website url https://fungen.000webhostapp.com/ by default points to index.php I added the below meta tags to my index.php. I tried to debug with the same url after some time but, It is showing the same warning as before.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can only hit the "let us know" link, there´s nothing else you can do. things like that cannot just be removed on your side, they are there for a reason.

Comment: Step 1: Get your own, proper domain name - so that you are not in danger of being considered as ”sitting in the same boat” with whatever spammers and other shady folks are probably using `*.000webhostapp.com` for their stuff.